# RadioButton setText from another class

Tags: java, swing, class, user-interface

Hi I have two classes A and B. In class A I executed the query and wants to set the result of query as a text of JRadioButton. The JRadioButton is in the class B and I have tried all possible ways but I could not.
How can I access the GUI of one class from another? There are some guidance available but it is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create a public method setButtonText(String text) in B, which takes a String as an argument and is callable from A. You can then write your button.setText(text) command into that method and therefore transmit the String you want to display from A to B.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't really understand what you meant but the easiest way to have full "bidirectional" access **is to have an instance of class A in class B
and an instance of B in A**

create an instance of A
create an instance of Bset the inner instance of each one by the other
setInnerInstanceofA(b)
setInnerInstanceofB(a)

Comment: Please if some one just write a small code here to explain? My string which I needs transfer to the radio button in another class is in "ArrayList". So how can I transfer this string to another class GUI: MyList.add(some text).. This "Sometext needs to be the text of radiobutton